# What does @$a or $a = ... mean in PHP?

Tags: php, operators

I have seen in a TwitterOAuth's library of PHP this code:

```
function __construct($http_method, $http_url, $parameters=NULL) {
    @$parameters or $parameters = array();
    //...
}
```

What does the operator or mean in this case?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` evaluates the right-hand side (`$parameters = array()`) only if the left-hand side is a "falsy" value.

In this case, it can be read:

> Set `$parameters` to `array()` unless `$parameters` is already set

The `@` is unrelated to the `or`. That is the error-suppression operator. In this case, it lets you test `$parameters` even if `$parameters` has not yet been assigned to. Typically this would cause an error, as it's a pretty commonly accepted [best-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/229044) to turn on error reporting when you attempt to read from a variable that has not yet been assigned to.

Comment: Note that the `@` is entirely superfluous, since `$parameters` is part of the function declaration and it will never throw an error under any circumstances.

Comment: @deceze Very true, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorthand for

```
if( empty($parameters) ) {
    $parameters = array();
}
```

The first part of the expression  `$parameters`  will output a notice and evaluate to false if $parameters is not set. The @ symbol suppresses that notice. Note that since $parameters is one of the function parameters it will always be set, so the error suppression is not necessary. The second part of the expression is only executed if the first part evaluates to false.

More generally, when determining the value of a boolean expression containing and OR (at the top level), PHP will stop evaluating once it finds a truthy value.

For example the following if statement will always be entered, and the second part of the expression will never be evaluated:

```
if( true || $anything ) {
     //will always be executed
}
```

As a side note, I think it is better to be expressive rather than clever. The code you posted requires minimal typing, but even if you understand what's happening it may take longer to grasp.

Comment: Note that in this case, `$parameters` is part of the function declaration and will never be not set.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't notice that. Since that is the case the error suppression is unnecessary.